# View base type's members in Resharper File Structure window?

Tags: c#, resharper

I've found that Resharper's "File Structure" window (Ctrl+Alt+F) is a *fantastic* tool for quickly visualizing,  organizing & regionizing a file's code. My one gripe is that I haven't found a way to see a composite view that includes inherited members.

Is there any way to do this with Resharper (or if not, another tool)?

Ideally same-named regions would be shown as merged, with inherited members preceding derived ones in each region. Lighter text and a suffix using the declaring type's name could indicate member inheritance. Inherited members should still be navigable. Unsorted/regioned stuff would presumably be ordered my member type and visibility.

My usual layout goes like this:

- Nonpublic fields & properties at the top
- Constructors
- Public fields, properties
- Implementation methods
- Other public methods
- Nonpublic methods
- Static members precede instance members within above

Answer (score 3):

Actually no, "File structure" is just that: file structure. It is not a class view. In case of a partial class you only see the methods, regions and so on as defined in the file whose structure is displayed.

Comment: Hmm, good point; maybe what I'm looking for would more aptly be titled a "Class Structure" view.

Comment: I use the Class Structure a lot, fanboy like you so to say, and sometimes get into habit mixing it with a class view.

Answer (score 2):

The plain VS Object Browser can give you a composite view (but without any grouping/ordering of members).